# Is there a git command that attempts a pull before pushing everytime?

Tags: git, git-merge, git-push, git-pull, git-alias

When I work on git repositories by myself, there is no reason to ever pull before pushing.

When I work with others, it is recommended that I perform a pull before attempting to push-- well, either a pull, or a checkout, and then get the changes merged in.
Either way, I can not push by normal means, until I am up-to-date with the master, so it is a good habit to pull before pushing everytime(so I've been told).
90% of the time I pull, it's either already up-to-date or a fast-forward.

Is there a `git push`-like command that automatically does a `pull` first, and only halts the push when there are actual merge conflicts?

I suppose I could make an alias, but I wanted to first check if there was an already built-in command for it.

Comment: "so it is a good habit to check before pushing everytime" --- there is no technical reason for doing that. If there is something git will just reject your `push`. Even working in an environment with > 20 developers in a single repository I don't `fetch` before `push` explicily

Answer (score 3):

> it is recommended that I perform a pull before attempting to push

Then it is recommended wrong. Just push. The act of pushing asks whether it is possible to push. If there's a reason why you can't push, you won't be able to push. *Then* you can worry about what to do.

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing that does exactly what you and I think it would also encourage bad work-flow habits, because you end up pushing code that is not tested. Just because something merges cleanly, it still could be horribly broken.

`git push` is already going to reject if you are not up-to-date with the remote. I will usually fetch the changes, review them, rebase my unpushed changes on top of them, and then go ahead.

If you find that you have too many commits coming in to do that (usually the case when everybody hammers commits on top of master), I would suggest switching to a branching based workflow. This isolates changes to their features, keeps history clean, and gives you a single integration step.

Answer (score 0):

I use a "done" alias that stashes my uncommitted changes, switches to master, pulls from remote, merges my current branch to master, pushes to remote, switches back to my branch and rebases against master.